# How to setup user signon authentication in Mochiweb?

Tags: mochiweb

It appears that erlang's mochiweb does not have any configuration that allows to setup a logon redirect user authentication. How could this be implemented ?

Answer (score 1):

Mochiweb is a low-level library and as such it doesn't have any authentication/authorization layer out of the box. You need to implement such functionality by yourself.

There is a lot to take into consideration when implementing such system by yourself, but take a look at [this answer](https://github.com/mochi/mochiweb.git)

To simplify things a bit, you can third party log-in services such as [persona](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/persona/). Even if you use third party services you still need a persistence layer where you save at least a list of registered users and a way to get information from forms or javascript. Check out this [tutorial](http://alexmarandon.com/articles/mochiweb_tutorial/#basic-request-handling) on how to access request information. For the persistence, erlang comes with ets/dets and mnesia so that you don't need to install any extra software, at least at the beginning.